# Fit doesn't take the label

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

I'm making my schema with `tikz` and I want to add a background. 
To do this, I use the `fit` but it doesn't take the label of my node.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{31,22,70}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{21,126,251}
\begin{document}  
       \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            scale=0.8,
            transform shape,
            %show background rectangle,
            background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
            box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
            ]
            \coordinate (b) at (current page.center);
            \node [
                label={[xshift=1cm,yshift=-2cm ]\Large{Cloud central}}, 
            ] (cloud)at(b)[scale=1.3]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
            \node[right =-0.1cm of cloud,rounded corners=3mm, label=above:{xx}] (heiafr) [draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=5cm] {};
            \node [
                label=below:\Large{Edge cloud a},below left = of cloud  
            ] (eca)at(b)[scale=.7]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
            \node [
                label=left:\Large{Edge cloud b}, left =3cm of cloud
            ] (ecb)at(b)[scale=.7]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
            \node [
                label=above:\Large{Edge cloud c}, above left = of cloud
            ] (ecc)at(b)[scale=.7]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
            \node [] ()at(eca)[]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
            \node [] ()at(ecb)[]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
            \node [] ()at(ecc)[]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
            \node [label=below:{Orchestrateur}] (sc)at(heiafr)[]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};

            \draw [thick,mycolor,->](heiafr) .. controls  (cloud).. (eca)node[very near start, above]{Orchestre};
            \draw [thick,mycolor,->](heiafr) .. controls  (cloud).. (ecb)node[very near start, right]{};
            \draw [thick,mycolor,->](heiafr) .. controls  (cloud).. (ecc)node[very near start, right]{};

            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \node[fill=mycolor2!20,rounded corners=1mm,draw,thick,dashed,fit=(ecb)(eca)(ecc)(sc),inner sep=7mm](){};
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{xxx}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output :[image] (I know it's kind of messy)

Thanks

Comment: Off topic: Avoid naming your colors with `mycolor` or `mycolor2` etc. At least make it `mycyan` or `mygreen`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this post :)